# ImportXML on Google Sheets -- How to import tag text that *follows* a specific tag text

Tags: html, jquery, google-sheets, xpath

Complete newbie with this, so appreciate advice.

I know how to get a tag's contents if it has a unique id, but many websites are like the following, where I want the content of a tag following another tag with a specific String as the content.

Is there a way to try to do a conditional expression OR extract the entire section and run regex OR a better way?

Thanks!

In Example 1, I want "May 11, 2021" which follows the following tags:

```
<div class="a-section a-spacing-small a-text-center rpi-attribute-label">
<span>Publication date</span>
</div>
<div class="a-section a-spacing-small a-text-center">
<span class="rpi-icon book_details-publication_date"></span>
</div>
```

In Example 2, I want "September 7, 2021"

---

Example 1:

```
<li class="a-carousel-card rpi-carousel-attribute-card" role="listitem" aria posinset="3">
<div class="a-section rpi-attribute-content">
<div class="a-section a-spacing-small a-text-center rpi-attribute-label">
 <span>Publication date</span>
</div>
<div class="a-section a-spacing-small a-text-center">
 <span class="rpi-icon book_details-publication_date"></span>
</div>
<div class="a-section a-spacing-none a-text-center rpi-attribute-value">
 <span>May 11, 2021</span>
</div>
</div>
</li>
```

Example 2:

```
<li><span class="a-list-item">
<span class="a-text-bold">Publication date
&rlm;
:
&lrm;
</span>
<span>September 7, 2021</span>
</span></li>
```

Comment: share the url you want to scrape

Answer (score 0):

Example #1, try this xpath

```
"//div[@class='a-section a-spacing-none a-text-center rpi-attribute-value']/span"
```

Example #2

```
"//span[@class='a-list-item']/span[2]"
```